# Change key setting from qwerty to azerty in Unity

Tags: unity, keyboard

How can I change the default key for walking with the player in Unity. At this moment I can do this with <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd> and <kbd>S</kbd> *(or something)*. But because I work with an azerty keyboard, I'll change it to <kbd>Z</kbd>, <kbd>Q</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd> and <kbd>D</kbd>. How can I do this (only for the game)?

Comment: Do you know how to use the [Input Manager](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-InputManager.html)? Or are you looking for a way to do this programatically/to change keyboard layouts at runtime?

Comment: @DMGregory: Input manager is good, but I've already found it by an answer from Alexandr Skornyakov.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the editor choose Edit → Project Settings → Input and change there the size of array or just change the values.

Answer (score 2):

To switch to AZERTY keyboard:

#### Input Manager

Unity -> Edit -> Project Settings -> Input Manager

- Horizontal: "q" instead of "a"
- Vertical: "z" instead of "w"

#### Shortcuts

- Unity -> Edit -> Shortcuts -> 3D Viewport: choose
  Forward Z, Left Q, Down A